# Ender 3 Max Neo Table Size

Tags: creality-ender-3

I'm seriously considering purchasing an Ender 3 Max Neo, but I'm unsure if I'll be able to fit it on my desk (i.e. I'm not sure if my desk is deep enough)

The specs report the machine dimensions as being 516 mm x 582 mm x 590 mm.  When I look at pictures of the unit it appears the rod for the Y rail protrudes past the front of the main unit, so I'm hoping I can get away with a table that is less than 582 mm deep.

Does anyone know how deep a table I will need to support this unit, assuming the table is hard up against a wall?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to find some measurements on the Ender 3 Max Neo to help you out, but, with the help of question [How to calculate linear Y rod length for a larger replacement bed?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6394/how-to-calculate-linear-y-rod-length-for-a-larger-replacement-bed) and some [videos on the Ender 3 Max Neo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p82TT4tNsb4&t=5s) we should be able to come up with the space needed in the back and front.

The Y-axis carriage has 6 V-slot rollers running on a 4040 aluminum extrusion profile:

[image]

When you know the pitch between the rollers (you need the distance between the first and the last roller) and the diameter of the wheels, you will be able to calculate the overhang of heated bed. Since I have no access to this printer I cannot measure this, but we can make some engineering "guestimations".

[image]

From the image above you can deduce that about one third of the bed "overhangs" (beware of the perspective!).

[image]

Similarly, you can calculate the length of the Y-axis tensioner to be about 55 mm extending in front of the 4040 extrusion; this implies the bed extends about 80 mm in front of the tensioner.

[image]

The back has a NEMA 17 stepper of 42 mm, so an overhang of 90 mm.

This implies that the table should at least be 582 mm + 80 mm + 90 mm = 752 mm deep to fit the bed within the table dimension. At the back you need some space for the bed to reach the home position (when the table has a wall behind it), but you can have the printer extending the bed at the front over the table.

Comment: Thank you for your effort with this answer.   I'm not sure its right though - I have just visited my local 3d print supplier and had a look at various machines.  While they did not have this exact model, they did have another Creality model with a 300x300 usable print bed in the same style, and this will fit fine on my 500mm deep table even with the board totally pushed back (**albeit with with the overhang sticking out** - and I wonder if this is where your answer veers from my requirement? )